# How to make javac compiler write the output to both file and console?

Tags: ant, javac

I am running javac task using ***ant*** and I send the output to a log file using *-Xstdout* compiler argument for reporting purposes, but I would like the output also still being send to the console so hudson can capture it for on screen review.

Is there a way for this to be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just came across another alternative using the recorder task.
Nearer as you don't have to introduce new targets.

```
<compile >
    <record name="log.txt" action="start"/>
    <javac ...
    <record name="log.txt" action="stop"/>
<compile/>
```

Comment: what's the meaning of `<compile>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

use the ant task with an output attribute to call a target that has the javac task.

e.g.

```
<target name="javac" depends="libs" description="Compile java source">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <ant target="actual-javac" output="javac.log"/>
</target>

<target name="actual-javac">
    <javac .../>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use tee on any process on the command line to output to the console and a file:

```
>myprocess.sh | tee myprocess.log
```

will print the output of myprocess.sh both to the console and myprocess.log.

Comment: I know how to do that in command line. My question is how to do that from ***ant***?