# How to see the compiler output when running javac through an Ant task?

Tags: java, ant, output, javac

Is there any clearly explained and simple way to see the compiler output when running `javac` through an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) task?

Here is my `javac` Ant tag:

```xml
<javac srcdir="${myproject.src}" destdir="${myproject.class}">
    <!-- ... -->
</javac>
```

Here is the only error message I get:

```
/path/to/build.xml:42: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The problem is that I don't know how to *see the compiler error output for details*...

---

Few configuration elements that may help:

- Ant 1.6.5
- Windows 7 x64
- Java 1.6.0_20 x32
- Launching targets via Eclipse

---

I know there are some related answered questions on SO, but none of them really answers this simple questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275552/1225328: I can't add the specific library that allows the `compile` tag;
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1264622/1225328: this manages Ant's output rather than the compiler's one;
- [Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8667798/1225328): too vague to solve anything;
- [Ant : Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12617618/1225328): no answer...
- etc.

Comment: Before the error message you get, don't you see `[javac] ...`?

Comment: @sp00m do you see the error details when ant is run from  command line. I guess problem is related to eclipse than ant.

Comment: If you dont see any `[javac]` it might be a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, see here in [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579073/javac-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-when-running-ant-from-eclipse/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `verbose="true"` attribute.

> Asks the compiler for verbose output; defaults to no.

You already mentioned in the comments that this doesn't print the cause of your error.  Well I think something else is going on in your situation.  I have a sample project and either way the cause of my error was printed.  Here's the output with `verbose="false"`:

```
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Projects\MavenSandbox\target\classes
[javac] C:\Projects\MavenSandbox\mavensandbox.xml:284: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Projects\MavenSandbox\target\classes
[javac] C:\Projects\MavenSandbox\src\main\java\com\sandbox\Sandbox.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         System.out.prinln("Hello, I\'m the best!");
[javac]                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   method prinln(String)
[javac]   location: variable out of type PrintStream
[javac] 1 error
```

Something strange and specific to your code is causing the bad error message.  Can you create a sample project that reproduces the error?

---

As you mentioned, `debug="true"` is not the attribute you're looking for.

> Indicates whether source should be compiled with debug information; defaults to off. If set to off, -g:none will be passed on the command line for compilers that support it (for other compilers, no command line argument will be used). If set to true, the value of the debuglevel attribute determines the command line argument.

You know when you get stack trace and it has line numbers in it?  That's what `debug="true"` does.  If it's off, you don't get line numbers.

Comment: Where do you add the `verbose="true"`? I've got the same problem, generated build.xml using Eclipse, and it only says `somepath/build.xml:34: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.` I've added it to the only <javac> tag as an attribute. Still cannot see compiler error output anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

The problem also occurs when the java-compiler itself cannot start. As an example, when the defined heap is too big. The java2 task of Intellij would display the information

```
Using external javac compiler
Compilation arguments:
...
'-J-Xmx1600m'
...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

and the cause in the build.xml file, in my case:

```
<property name="compiler.args" value="-J-Xmx1600m"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" debug="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
            </classpath>
</javac>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message with no further information.  The problem ended up being one of my .jar files was corrupted.  Replacing that .jar file solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the attribute [debug](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

```
<javac srcdir="${myproject.src}" destdir="${myproject.class}" debug="true>
    <!-- ... -->
</javac>
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything (I had it already on)... Where should then be the compiler's output?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Using `verbose`, Ant's output is *longer* but it still doesn't affect the compiler's output AFAIK...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried it before I answered your comment.

Comment: @sp00m _AFAIK_ thought you were assuming. Gonna try and find something else.

Comment: You should try to execute your ant script outside eclipse and see if you get a different output.